# How long does it take to verify previous immigration history in Germany?

Tags: visa, working-visas, germany, blue-card

Yesterday, I went to German Embassy in New Delhi to submit my documents for a blue card visa. The visa officer told me that, since I have lived in Germany in past and am now I’m applying again, they would ask the officials in Germany to do a verification of my previous stay and, after the verification report, she will issue me the visa. The officer couldn't specify how long the verification takes, only that it could be from 3 to 5 weeks, or more.

I lived in Germany for a year under the blue card employment scheme before coming back to India. I got another job in a different company and am applying for a visa again.

Does anyone with the same situation have any clue about what this verification is all about and how much time it usually takes?